# How to import AC3D files?

Tags: import

Using Blender 2.66 with Ubuntu 13.10.
How to import AC3D files?
I do not see an option for this under user preferences.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [majic79's *Blender-AC3D*](https://github.com/majic79/Blender-AC3D) addon. It is a port of the one that existed for Blender 2.49 and the author seems to update it every now and then.

> What is it?
>   It's a few python scripts to import/export AC3D data into and out of Blender 2.63+. For earlier Blender 2.6x versions you need an older revision of the plugin (https://github.com/majic79/Blender-AC3D/tree/BL2.62)
>
> Known Issues:
>
> - Exporter:
>
>   - Export packed .blend images is untested...
>   - It will either export everything, or everything that's selected. Default
>       behaviour is to export everything, if you want to only export those items
>       that you can see (ie, in the render scene), then select all those items and
>       check the "Selection Only" option on the export dialog.
>   - There's an option "Export Render Layer" - ie, only export what's currently
>       visible - this doesn't work, but is in the plan
> - Importer:
>
>   - No ngons yet.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The addon noted above does not function with Blender 2.66

Comment: @robgrune It is working for me in the latest build of Blender 2.69. Did you follow the instructions? Try searching ac3d after putting it in your scripts folder. http://i.stack.imgur.com/NItKB.png

Comment: Thanks for reply. I installed again. Followed directions in readme file. The key is to find the blender scripts addons folder with root permission, so to put the ac3d folder into the addons. Then configure Blender preferences to add the import/export function. Now working. Great!

Comment: I have a fork of this project running in Blender 2.80 https://github.com/jentron/Blender-AC3D import works, but as of today export does not.

Answer (score 3):

The Majic79 github has become inactive, the import-export script is still being maintained however. It is tested with Blender up to version 2.79, with many bugfixes and more complete format compliance.

It can now be found here: [Blender-AC3D](https://github.com/NikolaiVChr/Blender-AC3D) add-on.

And here for 2.80: [Blender-AC3D 2.80](https://github.com/NikolaiVChr/Blender-AC3D/tree/2.80) add-on (beta)

Answer (score 1):

This add-on was updated to 2.80 Stable today, it can be found here https://github.com/NikolaiVChr/Blender-AC3D/tree/2.80